# Authentication using Using DIrectMail SDK?

Tags: alibaba-cloud

I want to use the Direct Mail SDK(Java) directly within client application which is distributed across. The way to authenticate users within the application, I need to provide access keys as below,

`IClientProfile profile = DefaultProfile.getProfile("cn-hangzhou", "<your accessKey>", "<your accessSecret>");`

How can I prevent user to know the Access Keys and still prevent the need of third-party API? Is it possible?

Answer (score 1):

First, it is bad practice to code an application that requires secrets that runs on the client. You should manage everything on the server and provide an API that the client software interfaces with.

Second, there is no way to hide those credentials once passed to the client. You could encrypt the credentials but at some point the client application will need to decrypt them. Even amateur programmers can figure out how you are processing your credentials.

Ignoring the above advice, Alibaba Cloud supports STS which provides temporary access keys. Using your Alibaba credentials, you would call AssumeRole which creates temporary access keys giving the user permission call DirectMail. You can limit the time that the credentials are valid. The range is 900 to 3600 seconds. After that duration the keys become invalid.

Keep in mind that 900 seconds is a long time. A bad actor getting access to those keys could send thousands of emails using your account. Therefore implement strong user authentication, STS and temporary access keys.

If you think that just keeping your interface secret is enough, don't. There are millions of script kiddies on the Internet poking at every IP address. Launch a new ECS instance and you will see attacks within hours.

Answer (score 0):

As you said since it is a Java Web Application(assuming), currently I think of something using similar to JBOSS Vault to store the access keys securely.

If it is some standalone client application still you can use some encryption methodologies to store the data. But this will only prevent easy access to the data/keys. But it is not impossible. The best bet would be creating another third-party API